# Turing Decidable

Tags: turing-machines, automata, finite-automata, undecidability

```
M = (Q, Σ, Γ, δ, q1, qaccept, qreject), where
Q ={q1, q2, qaccept, qreject}, 
Σ = {0, 1}, 
Γ = {0, 1, U},
```

and transition function δ is as follows:

```
δ (q1, U) = (q1, U, R)
δ (q1, 0) = (q2, U, R)
δ (q1, 1) = (q2, U, R)
δ (q2, U) = (qaccept, U, R) δ (q2, 0) = (q1, U, R)
δ (q2, 1) = (q1, U, R)
```

is L Turing - decidable? From what I know, a language L is turing decidable if there is a turing machine M such that M decides L (M is a decider and L=L(M)).

What would be the language that M recognises? I am very new to Turing languages so not quite sure how to read the transition function. I know that a language is decidable if it halts (rejects or accepts) for every input string, but thats about it.

Comment: Just to get you started, the transition function tells you what symbol to write, which state to change to and which way to move the head, given the state you're currently in and the symbol you're looking at on the tape. For example, the first one, $\delta(q_{1},\sqcup) \rightarrow (q_{1},\sqcup,R)$ means that if you're in state $q_{1}$, and the tape has a blank, then you stay in state $q_{1}$, write a blank to the tape, then move the head one cell to the right. This should be enough for you to draw a transition diagram, or puzzle out a bit more.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to figure out whether the machine you describe is a decider? Or if the language of that machine is decidable? (i.e. is there _another_ TM that given a string, tells you whether it's in the language of the first machine or not?)

Comment: @LukeMathieson - So what I need to do is prove that M is NOT a decider and also using mathematical term, describe the language the M recognises (i.e. prove that L = L(M).

Comment: quick clarifying question, is the U meant to be a blank symbol, or actually a U?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck here: since every transition of your TM moves the head right, the state of this machine will never depend on the previous contents of the tape. This means that your TM will act as if it were a finite automaton, basing its transitions only on the current input symbol. In other words, your TM is essentially equivalent to this FA:

[image]

It's easy enough to define the language accepted by this FA. It consists of all strings of the form:

- (an arbitrary number of U's) followed by (any even-length string of 0's and 1's),
- repeated an arbitrary number of times,
- ending with 0u or 1u.

As a regular expression, this language is denoted by 
$$
(U + 00 + 01 + 10 + 11)^*(0 + 1)U
$$
Where $r + s$ represents the union of the sets denoted by the regular expressions $r$ and $s$. This, then, is the language, $L(M)$, of your original machine. Since the language is regular, it is certainly decidable, since a finite automaton will always eventually halt.

The question of whether your TM is a decider will depend on your local definition of what that means. Customarily, a TM is defined to be a decider if it eventually halts on every possible input. This machine will certainly do that, even though it will never enter $q_{\text{reject}}$, so under this definition your TM is indeed a decider. Be aware, though, that some authors require that a decider must eventually enter $q_{\text{accept}}$ or $q_{\text{reject}}$ and halt for *any* possible input, so under that definition, your TM wouldn't be a decider. Look at your notes to see which definition applies (from what you wrote, it seems to be the latter).

---

Another reasonable interpretation of this problem is that 'U' is intended to represent the blank character. Under this interpretation, the TM is definitely not a decider, since when given the empty string as input, namely when faced with a tape initially containing nothing but blanks, the TM will loop in state $q_1$ forever, thereby never halting. No matter which definition of a decider you choose, it's universally agreed that a decider must halt on all inputs, hence under this interpretation, the TM isn't a decider.

Comment: The TM won't halt. Assume $\sqcup$ is the tape blank symbol, and not an input symbol, this machine will loop infinitely on a blank tape (amongst other inputs). The machine is only a recogniser, which gels with the clarification in the comments to the question.

Comment: @LukeMathieson. You're right, of course. I missed the (perfectly reasonable) assumption that the OPs 'U' was to be interpreted as the visible space character. Under that interpretation, the TM is indeed not a decider, since it fails to halt on an empty input. Perhaps I should edit my answer.

Comment: actually that a good point. I'm assuming they're blanks, they could well be $u$s.